# Reading columns from text file without a clear delimiter

Tags: python-2.7

I have this text file: http://henke.lbl.gov/tmp/xray6286.dat
In which I would like to pull out the energy and transmission columns.

Unfortunately it doesn't have a clear delimiter - the words are separated by a series of spaces.

Running something like

```
with open('xray6286.dat', 'U') as data:
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=' ')
for line in reader:
    print line
```

would result in an output like:

```
['', 'Cu', 'Density=8.96', 'Thickness=100.', 'microns']
['', 'Photon', 'Energy', '(eV),', 'Transmission']
['', '', '', '', '5000.0', '', '', '', '', '', '0.52272E-07']
['', '', '', '', '5250.0', '', '', '', '', '', '0.42227E-06']
['', '', '', '', '5500.0', '', '', '', '', '', '0.24383E-05']
```

I can brute force it to give me the values I want with the following code:

```
import csv

energy = []
transmission = []

with open('xray6286.dat', 'U') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\n')
    for line in reader:
        if reader.line_num > 2:
            cleaned_line = []
            for word in line[0].split(' '):
                if word:
                    cleaned_line.append(word)
            energy.append(cleaned_line[0])
            transmission.append(cleaned_line[1])
```

But I was wondering if someone knew a more ..eloquent.. way for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [regex split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) method can separate the datapoints based on an arbitrary number of spaces.

```
import re

for word in re.split(r'\s+', line):
    print word
```

Comment: Whenever you can avoid using regex you should do so,  regex is expensive to compute.

Comment: @alfasin Okay, that's good to know. How much does precompiling the regular expression help? `spaces = re.compile(r'\s+'); spaces.split(line);`?

Comment: The compilation is not time consuming - it's the parsing part which is heavy.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Okay I'll keep that in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `if word:` is perfectly fine. Another option would be to `filter` out the nulls by replacing:

```
for word in line[0].split(' '):
```

with:

```
for word in filter(bool, line[0].split(' ')):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results in a data structure then itterate through it and delete the null entries. @alfasin suggested the best idea though, which is to use `filter`